# getting etag from 'google reader bundle' feed using universal feed parser in python

Tags: python, atom-feed, google-reader

I am using the universal feed parser library in python to get an atom feed. This atom feed has been generated using google reader after bundling several subscriptions.

I am able to receive the latest feeds, however the feedparser.parse(url) returns a FeedParserDict which doesnot have the etag or modified values. I unable to just check for the latest feeds because of this.

Does google reader send an etag value? if yes why isn't the feedparser returning it?

~Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Reader API does not support ETags or If-Modified-Since. However, it does support an `ot=<timestamp in seconds since the epoch>` parameter which you can use to restrict fetched data to items since you last attempted a fetch.